# Close vote -> Retracted -> exact duplicate vote impossible?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, retracted-close-votes

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810921) was tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) only, but the problem can't be reproduced and I voted to close it.

Then I noticed it's a CakePHP-Question that already has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545764) and has an answer.

So I added the tag [cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp) and retracted my vote.

But I can't vote any more to "close as duplicate". I **had to** request someone else to close as duplicate.

Why am I not able to vote-to-close after editing the question?

Comment: Still not marked as Duplicate! Can anyone please mark the Post as duplicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only ever get to vote **once** per post. You cannot change vote again after retracting.

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), to prevent voting shenanigans. Just leave a comment explaining that the post is a possible duplicate, and perhaps ask for some help in an appropriate chat room.

Comment: Then i think this is a Bug, not a Feature.

Comment: @PeterRader: where did you get the idea that you should be able to vote more than once?

Comment: @PeterRader It's the intended behavior of the designers.  That makes it *by definition* not a bug.  A bug is unintended functionality.  It can be behavior you don't like, sure.  That doesn't make it a bug, just behavior you don't like.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because i Rectracted the vote, a rectraction is a complete remove of the voting. So my vote-count is zero, and to reach the `vote-once` rule i need to vote i think. But ok, its by design.

Comment: @Servy, as Martijn answered my duplicate-vote is pure **shenanigan** and the intended function to prevent a vote-duplicate is perfectly right! Shame on me! ;D

Comment: @PeterRader A retraction is not a *removal* of anything. When you make a statement in court and then find out it's wrong, you retract it. But the statement has already been made, you can never completely undo that. You can't erase it from history. You can tell the jury "don't pay attention to that statement" and hope they ignore it, but it will always be hovering in the back of their minds. -- Your close vote *still exists*, it's just not being counted.

Comment: @animuson Ah ok cool. Why do i help others? Shame on me!

Comment: Used to be you couldn't retract Close votes at all.

Comment: Do i need more *likes* to vote a second time?

Comment: @PeterRader As Martijn explained, you can't change your vote. You can't vote a second time. No amount of reputation will allow you to do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What sort of voting shenanigans is this supposed to prevent? I sometimes find that I need to change my vote, due to extra information being provided by the user. Ex, I first vote that they have not provided their code, and then the user provides their code, and it turns out to be non-reproducible typographical issue.

Comment: @mason: don't take the responsibility to close on your own shoulders and trust the community. If you had to retract your vote, then someone else will take over and close the post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is my experience that trusting the community does not work well for the less visited tags. It's already hard to get questions closed when there is no retraction involved.

Comment: @mason: and as for the shenanigans: imagine two sets of users quibbling over wether the question should be closed, or for what reason. Group 1 closes, group 2 reopens and recloses, group 1 reopens and recloses, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps if a Close->Reopen->Reclose sequence happens, it could automatically notify moderator's to step in and settle the dispute? It'd be nice to "trust the community" but a lot of times questions slip into obscurity (even on higher profile tags) and so relying on others to notice isn't quite as effective as we might like.

Comment: @mason: related Meta.SE feature request for you: [Allow another close vote after retraction](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200391)

Comment: [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is open for (duplicate) close vote requests if you need to correct your close vote. Do read their [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) when joining to post a request.