# Recasting close vote for a different duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, retracted-close-votes

I recently voted to [close a question as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63375241/6865932), and I then retracted the close vote in hopes of recasting the close vote with a better duplicate. The problem is I can't recast the vote because I retracted the close vote.

[This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271250/6865932) does talk about this, but in a different context - one of recasting the vote after edits. In my case, I just found what I consider to be a better duplicate.

I understand the reasons for not having unlimited recasting of close votes as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200391/684852).

But I believe that it would be nice to be able to recast close votes at least for a limited number of times. Let's say, one or two more times for cases like this, where you made a mistake or found a better suited reason.

Comment: Just leave a comment, once it is closed gold badgers can fix it.

Comment: KevinB, I see, in this case it isn'tt closed, but it's not too bad, the dup is mostly adequate, just found a better one, I left a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gold badge holders (& moderators) can edit the duplicate target list, as explained here: [Edit duplicate closure target after close vote has been cast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328249/4014959)

So if you make a mistake, or find a better target, just write a brief comment containing the better link(s). You may be able to get assistance from a gold badger or mod in a chat room, but that's probably not necessary, unless the first dupe target you chose was *really* bad and the question has already been closed. :)

Comment: I see,  fortunately the first dup is not too bad so I'm not too worried, but I was just wondering, at least one recast could be useful and would limit the potencial for shenanigans.

Comment: @rene, nice, I'll do that, it seems like the way to go in cases like this.

Comment: @anastaciu I see I got my formatting of the chat message wrong. It is explained better (and correct) in the this SOCVR FAQ topic: https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests